# Is it possible to add the nodes of Binary Search Tree to a hashset or hashmap

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, binary-search-tree, hashset

Can we put the nodes of the BST inside either a HashMap or HashSet? If so how do we traverse the BST.This doubt arose while I was solving the TWO SUM BST.

Comment: so, what exactly you were trying ?? please show us the code

Comment: This was the question
_Given a Binary Search Tree and a target number, return true if there exist two elements in the BST such that their sum is equal to the given target._
. 
 public boolean findTarget(TreeNode root, int k) {
        
    }
I was actually stuck.I planned to add the node values to the HashSet. if the HashSet consists of k` - node.value then it will return true.

Answer (score 2):

You may put the nodes of a BinarySearchTree into a HashSet, or a HashMap (not sure what the Key,Value pairing would be for the Map). For the HashSet, I would simply traverse the BST in order. To solve the problem that you were given, I would tackle the problem like so:

```
// Returns true if the BST contains two nodes with elements that
// sum to k, otherwise false
public bool findTarget(TreeNode root, int k){
    if(root == null){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    return traverse(root, k, set);
}

// Traverses across the BST, in order, adding elements to the set
bool traverse(Node<T> node, int k, HashSet<Node<T>> set){
    // If the node has a left child, traverse it first
    if(node.left != null){
        return traverse(node.left, k, set);
    }
    // Check to see if the set contains the element that would sum
    // with the node we're checking's element to equal k
    if(set.contains(k-node.element)){
        return true;
    }
    // Add node's element to the set
    set.add(node.element);

    // If the node has a right child, traverse it after
    if(node.right != null){
        return traverse(node.right, k, set);
    }
    else{
        // No two node's with elements summing k exist in the BST,
        // since you reached the end and found nothing
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That would do.

Comment: @Darth_dk You may want to note the time complexity of such algorithm. traverse() would be called worst-case BST.size times, and the complexity within each traverse() would be constant, due to a HashSet's O(1) add() and contains() methods. So, the time complexity would be O(BST.size), if you're interested

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. A Binary Search Tree has data like any other, and that data can be stored into any other type of collection in Java. Before I tell you how to traverse the BST, let me explain what it is in case you don't know.

A Binary Search Tree is a way of organizing data. The top node is usually called the root, and any data that is less than it will be put to the left of it, and any data that is greater than it will be put to the right of it. These are called the children of it, and the other node is called the parent. For instance, if your root was 2, 1 would be placed to the left of it, and 3 would be placed to the right. However, a node can only have at most 2 children, and the left and right branches can only differ by at most a length of 1. In the case where they differ by more than one, some swapping needs to be done.

To traverse the tree, you must first start at the left branch. With each level you go down, you must first check if the node has a left child. If it does, then go down one level. Keep going down until there are no more left children. This means this is the lowest value. Go up one level, take that as your next value. If it has a right child, take that one next. Continue this until you get to the root. Next, take the root. Finally, traverse the right branch with the same logic. Go to the first right child, and only take if it has no left child. If it does, take the farthest left child. Then take the parent(s). Continue this until you get to the farthest right child, which will be your highest value.